# Is there any advantage to using simple syrup over just dissolving sugar and waiting a minute?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-life, physical-chemistry, chemical-compounds

When making coffee, I want to sweeten it with sugar. Many coffee shops offer [simple syrup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syrup#Simple_syrup) which is essentially just a solution of water saturated with sugar.

Obviously, this has the advantage that the sugar is already dissolved, but sugar usually dissolves pretty quickly in hot coffee.

My small knowledge of this area of physics tells me that it should be no different as long as the sugar is allowed to completely dissolve in the coffee.

Is there some other physical mechanism I'm missing?

edit: Also assume that to have space for the simple syrup, I had to pour out some coffee. So it's not a question of there simply being more liquid for sugar to be dissolved in if you add simple syrup.

Comment: For hot coffee, I don't see any advantage to using simple syrup over sugar. But around here, the coffee shops also sell lots of iced coffee drinks.

Answer (score 2):

Your coffee will remain hotter if you dissolve a unit of sugar in it, as opposed to a unit of sugar dissolved in cold water